# What is the proper method to give credits in lecture material

Tags: ethics, teaching, lecture-notes

To prepare the lecture material. I use the book, my own slides, but I also take a few slides from MIT or other top universities open courses. 
What is the best way to give credit? 
I must provide source information on each slide? 
Or Is it better to enlist all the resources/citations in the first/final slide?

Comment: Do as you'd expect your students to do; set an example.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it does not provide an explanation that helps the OP and other readers understand why this is a useful answer.

Comment: @BryanKrause Isn't it obvious? _Setting an example_ is a known concept. Elaborating would surely be condescending.

Comment: Clearly is it not obvious, as someone felt the need to person asked the question. This answer does not provide concrete guidance to the OP.

Comment: @eykanal I never suggested my answer nor the question was obvious (indeed, _someone felt the need to...ask_). The motivation behind my answer seems obvious. Others seemingly like my answer, since it was the top-voted answer (but has now been removed by administrators), so I presume some were happy with it.

Comment: @user2768 - It was removed by me. For sarcastic answers, upvotes simply indicate that people appreciate the sarcasm, they should not be read as a referendum on quality. This site is rife with examples of that.

Comment: @eykanal The answer was not sarcastic. It wasn't the first answer that came to me, but I think it is the best. Ironically, I don't think it is obvious, even though it seems so. At least, it wasn't obvious to me and until I thought through the question rather deeply. Was it obvious to you? (You've already acknowledged it wasn't obvious to others, since _someone felt the need to...ask...the question_.)

Answer (score 3):

Do you include the slides verbatim (e.g., by copying a pdf or image into your slides), or do you just base your slides on those other slides in the same way in which you might base them on a textbook?

In the first case, I think that a note on that slide (on the first slide, if you copy several slides in a row) is mandatory – probably not only a reference, but a copyright notice.

In the second case, I'd include the reference in a bibliography section, like for other journal papers or textbooks that you base your slides on. If I can avoid it, I prefer not to clutter every slide with details that are irrelevant for understanding the content.

Comment: I am doing the second case

Comment: @MBK Then it's one reference out of many, so treat it the same way as, say, a textbook.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to give credit?

Apply the same rules you'd use for slides presented at an academic event. Personally, I'd include source information in a footnote on each slide.

Comment: I ask them to cite at the end. The reason I like to put at the end because I want a clear screen to write on the slides during the online lecture. But I feel putting on each slide is is more appropriate.

Comment: Did you mean to post two answers?

Comment: @AzorAhai Yes, they're distinct

Comment: It is strange to give two different answers. Either they two pieces of advice are compatible, or they are incompatible. If compatible, they could be combined into one answer which explains both pieces of advice. If incompatible, that raises doubt about *both* answers as it is unclear whether you hold the opinion that that answer is the correct one.

Comment: @6005 They're incompatible: The OP asked for _the best_. I have two candidates, so I gave them both.

Comment: @user2768 This appears to have been covered on meta before [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/what-is-the-etiquette-of-providing-more-than-one-answer-to-the-same-question?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the answer is that having a single answer is preferred instead of two answers. I asked on meta [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4694/should-one-post-two-conflicting-answers-to-a-question?noredirect=1) (but then noticed the other question and closed as duplicate)

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it does not provide an explanation that helps the OP and other readers understand why this is a useful answer; in particular it provides no guidance that separates it from the other answer by the same user.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/86688)

Comment: @AloneProgrammer I don't understand: How is providing a personalised methodology not an answer?

Comment: @BryanKrause I consider the answers different. What is expected of students in class can be rather different to what academics do at conferences, because classroom/conference norms are different.