# Can I use the slides published in the course websites to teach in my own courses?

Tags: copyright, presentation

Stanford University (and others) usually publish slides/lecture notes on the corresponding websites.

For instance, this one: http://cs229.stanford.edu/

If I teach a course in the same topic, can I just use the slides/lecture notes? Do I need to acquire permission?

I will keep the name of Stanford on the slides and clearly stated that the slides are made by Stanford professors.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper method to give credits in lecture material](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/147149/what-is-the-proper-method-to-give-credits-in-lecture-material)

Answer (score 1):

- You need a license (from the copyright holder, here most likely Stanford University) to directly use their slides/parts of their slides or to make derivative use.

  - If the slides are publish under a license that allows you to reuse them, you're fine.
    Examples would be CC0, CC BY, CC BY-SA, CC BY-ND (careful with -NC variants, they may not be sufficient for your purpose, e.g. in my country already putting ads on a web site with a blog so it earns the server costs makes that blog commercial)
  - You can ask Stanford whether they allow you to use the slides (i.e., grant you a licence)
- You can always use the *ideas* behind the slides as inspiration to create your *own* slides.

  - Be careful since derivative works of their slides/images/diagrams need a license, see above.
  - Your slides need to constitute a new work of your own.
  - Example of inspiration: "It'a really good idea to point out the 'sample focus' change from LDA/QDA over LR to SVM" - then make your own slide on that topic.